# How Best to Write To BundleConfig From Nuget

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, nuget, nuget-package

I am creating a Nuget package for other developers on my team and I am condensing styles using SASS.

The package is packed with the appropriate dependencies for using SASS and it installs fine on a new MVC4 project.

My question is, certain changes need to be made by the Nuget package to the BundleConfig in App_Start but I am not certain the best way to go about automating this process.

I am attempting to use the install.ps1 approach to upsert the changes to the bundle config file but I am not sure if this is the best approach.

I want the end result to be zero effort for my team members to apply a Nuget to a solution and not have to do any editing of the BundleConfig.

Please let me know what the best plan is for making something like this happen.

It will need to set the namespace for the BundleConfig file get the default configs and replace them with new config statements for both styles and scripts.

The replacement will be boilerplate stuff so I should be able to include a file in my nuget package that has the intended changes, open the existing bundle config and dump my changes in.

I know little to no powershell but if you could point me to an article that would be great!

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)
$app_start = $project.ProjectItems | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "App_Start" }
$app_start.GetType().FullName | out-file "C:\Code\Test2.txt" -append
$app_start | Get-Member | out-file "C:\Code\Test2.txt" -append
$files = $app_start.ProjectItems
foreach($file in $files)
{$file.Name | out-file "C:\Code\Test2.txt" -append }
```

This is my current stab at getting to the BundleConfig.cs file.

I can list out the ProjectItems but I am not certain how to open the App_Start folder to get the BundleConfig.cs file.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$prjFileNameAndPath = $project.FileName
$arrFileNameAndPath = $prjFileNameAndPath.Split("\")
$pathLength = $arrFileNameAndPath.count - 1
$partToTrim = $arrFileNameAndPath[$arrFileNameAndPath.count - 1]

$index = 0
$destPath = ""
foreach($node in $arrFileNameAndPath)
{
   $index++
   if($index -le $pathLength) {
        $destPath += $node + "\"
   }
}

$destPath += "App_Start\BundleConfig.cs"
$destPath | out-file "C:\Code\Test.txt" -append

$content = Get-Content $destPath
$content | out-file "C:\Code\Test2.txt" -append

function Update-Text {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
    [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [System.String]
    $FilePath,

    [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
    [System.String]
    $MatchPattern,

    [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
    [System.String]
    $ReplacementPattern
)

BEGIN {
}

PROCESS {
    Write-Verbose "Replacing Content in $FilePath"
    Write-Verbose "Match pattern: $MatchPattern"
    Write-Verbose "Replace pattern: $ReplacementPattern"

    (Get-Content $FilePath) | % {$_ -replace $MatchPattern, $ReplacementPattern    } | Set-Content $FilePath
}
}
```

This got me down to the point of being able to Get-Content for the file.  I plan on using a regular expression to replace the text.

I had to basically build the path to the file based on the Project FileName property then crop the csproj filename out and append the App_Start\BundleConfig.cs to the path.

It's not pretty but it will work for what we need at my job.  Hope this helps someone.  If anyone knows of an easier way to alter contents of a file from a nuget install powershell script please chime in.  Happy coding and May the Force Be With You, Always!

Comment: Wow. Nothing but crickets for this question?

Comment: I'm searching for some examples, too. Thanks for posting this answer at least. FWIW - [Here's Microsoft's docs for NuGet install/uninstall powershell files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/analyzers-conventions)